# What kinds of icons do Chrome Extensions support?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons, firefox-addon-webextensions

Trying to make a Firefox WebExtension work in Chrome, I realized that Chrome's icon support must differ. I have been using a multiresolution icon that contains the icon in 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64, 128x128 and 256x256, which seemed to work in Firefox without any errors. In Chrome I get errors that the icon is not supported...
Is it possible that my format is corrupt or does Chrome simply not support multiresolution icons?
Do I really have to create individual files for every resolution?

Comment: As for multi-resolution, is it an ICO image? It's not cross-platform to begin with.

Comment: A quick info to get you going until someone points to or posts a full answer. Chrome reliably handles PNG and has problems with JPG/SVG on some platforms. I use 16, 32, 19, 38 for the toolbar and 128, 256 for chrome://extensions and webstore. 19 and 38 for the chromium-based forks that still use the old design and might keep doing it for a long time (Vivaldi, for example, draws its UI entirely in js).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is an ICO image. Multiresolution icons simply have multiple layers. I've worked on it on Linux and on Windows. I'm not sure what you mean by "not cross-platform to begin with".

Comment: It's a Windows icon format that's not used widely in other OS and thus not guaranteed to be supported. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format))